# content overlapping in Ipad landscape view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

my content is working fine in desktop and other small devices but in iPad landscape view ( screen size 1024pX768) I'm facing issue, when I clicked on the menu sidebar toggle it's overlapping on the existing content. we're using `bootstap 3`

I don't want overlap the div content its there in the area when menu toggle clicked.
[image]

[image]

In the first image, it looks fine when clicked on the toggle menu button it will be overlapped.

My HTML code is:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="box-hseader">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0 6px 0px 0px">
                <a class="btn btn-app boxFlat "   ng-click="totalComplaints()">
                    <div class="col-mds-3">
                        <span>Total: {{commonareacount||0}}</span>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0 6px">
                <a class="btn btn-app boxFlat"  ng-click="isSolved()">
                    <div class="col-mds-3">
                        <span>Solved: {{commonareacountsolved||0}}</span>

                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0 6px">
                <a class="btn btn-app boxFlat "  ng-click="isUnsolved()">
                    <div class="col-mds-3">
                        <span>Unsolved: {{commonareacountpending||0}}</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0 6px">
                <a class="btn btn-app boxFlat "  ng-click="isCancelled()">
                    <div class="col-mds-3">
                        <span>Cancelled: {{commoncanceled||0}}</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>




        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group form-inline pull-right rghtFlt">
                <select name="filterByRolenm" id="filterByRoleId" ng-model="roleFilter"
                    ng-change="showFilteredComplaints(CommonAreaComplaintsCopy)" class="form-control">
                    <option value="All">All roles</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="resPerson in personnelResType" value="{{resPerson.res_id}}">{{resPerson.res_type}}</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="updateFilteredList('getcomplaints', complaintsCopy)"
                    placeholder="Search ">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right iPhn5cbtn" data-toggle="modal"
                data-whatever="@getbootstrap" data-target="#exportComplaintsId"
                ng-click="getComplaintId(1)" data-keyboard="false">Export
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

My CSS code is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){
       .rghtFlt{
        float: none !important;
    }
 }


 @media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    .rghtFlt{
        float: none !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     .rghtFlt{
        float: none !important;
    }
 }

.boxFlat {
position: relative;
border-radius: 3px;
background: #ffffff;
margin-bottom: 20px;
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 6px rgba(0, 9, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Toggle Navigation JS Script:

```
 // toggle nav bar
function openNav() {


  var marginLeftContent = document.getElementById("user_name");

  if (marginLeftContent.style.display === 'none') {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('displayIcon');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
    document.getElementById("sidebar-left").style.width = "230px";
    // document.getElementsByClassName("displayIcon")[0].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("user_name").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("main-header").style.marginLeft = "228px";
    document.getElementById("main-footer").style.marginLeft = "230px";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundColor = '#ecf0f5';
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundImage = 'none';
    document.getElementById("content-wrapper").style.marginLeft = '230px';

  } else {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('displayIcon');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById("sidebar-left").style.width = "70px";
    // document.getElementsByClassName("displayIcon")[0].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("user_name").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("main-header").style.marginLeft = "70px";
    document.getElementById("main-footer").style.marginLeft = "70px";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundColor = '#ecf0f5';
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundImage = 'none';
    document.getElementById("content-wrapper").style.marginLeft = '69px';

  }

}
```

Comment: You should consider changing classes via javascript instead of setting styles. It will be easier to work with.

Comment: Obviously you run out of space. As you don't provide the css for `box-hseader` you can only guess. Kind of looks like you're using flex on it without wrap.

Comment: @l0w_skilled create classes for particular div?

Comment: @l0w_skilled  removed `box-hseader` also doesn't work for me that is the custom CSS class

Comment: Can you write common English sentences? It's very unclear what you want. `my content is working fine in desktop and other small devices but in iPad landscape view ( screen size 1024pX768), when I clicked on the menu toggle`, this is not a sentence.

Comment: @Sanne my code was working in all devices except iPad landscape view ( screen size 1024pX768), we used `openNav()` for menu sidebar extend, I'm facing an issue in  iPad landscape view

Answer (score 0):

Finally achieved my self what I'm expecting the result, I created the custom column width code instead of bootstrap width class after that it is working

My CSS code:

```
    .col-md-1-complnts {
    width: 12.29%;
}
.col-md-1-complnts-four {
    width: 5%;
}

.col-md-4-complnts-search {
    width: 41% ;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-1-complnts-four col-xs-2 " style="position: initial !important;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info " ng-click="backtodashboard()"><i
        class="fa fa-reply"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6" style="position: initial !important; margin-top: 0px !important;    margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" style="width: 100%"
        data-target="#complaisntsmodel" data-whatever="@getbootstrap" ng-click="complaints();complaintsresp();setFormPristine()"
        data-keyboard="false"> 
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
        Rise Complaint
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 6px 0px 0px">
        <a class="btn btn-app boxFlat" ng-click="totalPlayComplaints()">
            <div class="col-mds-3">
                <span>Total:Play {{playareacount||0}}</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 6px 0px 0px">
        <a class="btn btn-app boxFlat"  ng-click="isPlaySolved()">
            <div class="col-mds-3">
                <span>Solved: {{playareacountsolved||0}}</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 6px 0px 0px">
        <a class="btn btn-app boxFlat "  ng-click="isPlayUnsolved()">
            <div class="col-mds-3">
                <span>Unsolved: {{playareacountpending||0}}</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 6px 0px 0px">
        <a class="btn btn-app boxFlat "  ng-click="isPlayCancelled()">
            <div class="col-mds-3">
                <span>Cancelled: {{playAreacanceled||0}}</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-10  " style="position: initial !important;" >
        <div class="form-group form-inline ">
            <select name="filterByRolenm" id="filterByRoleId" ng-model="roleFilter" style="width: 100%"
            ng-change="showFilteredComplaints(CommonAreaComplaintsCopy)" class="form-control">
                <option value="All" >All roles</option>
                <option ng-repeat="resPerson in personnelResType" value="{{resPerson.res_id}}">{{resPerson.res_type}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4-complnts-search col-xs-12 " style="position: initial !important; margin-bottom: 10px; ">
        <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="updateFilteredList('getcomplaints', complaintsCopy)"
            placeholder="Search ">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-1-complnts col-xs-6" style="position: initial !important; margin-top: 0px !important;    margin-bottom: 15px;" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success " style="width: 100% !important" data-toggle="modal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap" data-target="#exportComplaintsId" ng-click="getComplaintId(2)" data-keyboard="false">Export
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nothing changed anything in toggle navigation JS